# How to find the broken links in a website by providing the URL say for example 'www.hammacher.com'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, httpurlconnection

Am using the below code to find the broken links in a website. But if i want to find for the whole website inclusive of the internal links how can i do it? Please someone advise. Thank you

To check the broken links in a web page

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){

        url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

        System.out.println(url);

        if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
            continue;
        }

        if(!url.startsWith(homePage)){
            System.out.println("URL belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
            continue;
        }

        try {
            huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

            huc.connect();

            respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

            if(respCode >= 400){
                System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: You can ask for site map URLs instead of traversing all the page on site.

Comment: Currently, the code is not fetching the internal URLs say the product pages in the website 'www.hammacher.com'. Product pages are internal links. Navigation would be Electronics tab-> New arrivals-> then products... Please advise where i have to make the changes in the code

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was perfecto. To check the status of the links once you retrieve the `href` attributes from the `<a>` tags you can write a function which will accept the `href` as argument and print the relevant *status* as follows:

- Function to check the status of the links:

  ```
  private void CheckingLink(String linkURL) 
  {

          try {
              URL url = new URL(linkURL);
              HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(5000);
              httpUrlConnect.connect();
              if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) 
              {
                  System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
              }
              if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 500) 
              {
                  System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
              }
              if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 404) 
              {
                  System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
              }
              if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 402) 
              {
                  System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
              }
              if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) 
              {
                  System.out.println(
                          linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - " + httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
              }

              } catch (IOException e) 
                  {
                      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                  }
      }
  ```
- Calling the function `CheckingLink()`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
  System.out.println("Number of WebElements on this page : "+elements.size());
  for (int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
  {
      WebElement ele = elements.get(i);
      String url = ele.getAttribute("href");
      CheckingLink(url);
  }
  ```
- The execution result on the url https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us produces the following output on the console:

  ```
  Number of WebElements on this page : 105
  https://in.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.partner=none&.src=fp - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://cricket.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.finance.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/tagged/celebrity - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/tagged/movies - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.mobile.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/everything/ - OK
  https://in.answers.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.groups.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.messenger.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/weather - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/everything/world - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fin.yahoo.com - OK
  https://mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.partner=none&.src=fp - OK
  https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fin.yahoo.com - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us#mega-bottombar-mail - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us#Main - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us#Aside - OK
  https://mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.partner=none&.src=fp - OK
  https://cricket.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.finance.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/tagged/movies - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/tagged/celebrity - OK
  http://in.travelinspirations.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.yahoo.com/everything/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/video/32-episode-1-095405056.html - OK
  https://cricket.yahoo.net/scores/india-vs-afghanistan-oneoff-test-14th-june-2018-inaf06142018185950-summary - OK
  https://cricket.yahoo.net/scores/india-vs-afghanistan-oneoff-test-14th-june-2018-inaf06142018185950-summary - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/fed-bengaluru-traffic-techie-rides-085447032.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/photos-eid-ul-fitr-celebrations-slideshow-wp-095013253.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/quick-look-actor-plays-race-slideshow-wp-102506088.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/five-crucial-things-know-blood-103318158.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/boy-america-contracts-bubonic-plague-113108819.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/janhvi-khushi-anshula-holiday-london-dad-boney-kapoor-064018621.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/janhvi-khushi-anshula-holiday-london-dad-boney-kapoor-064018621.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/janhvi-khushi-anshula-holiday-london-dad-boney-kapoor-064018621.html - OK
  https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=8j5uUzIGIS8bthoOIIlefINlCyUX0sMagCIuZQ05jmBfB74DwldI_rYOX1OS5kBByKf6VXv1ZfletO8DFuwVrss1EH7zcp7sC3mOkIDCDckHezCh6uetN9gABHeBIVJhY_Gh2YQZYlGcNjg0Ls4p9bZZt6jMNKDm_Deq0awAlb3iWN9MmuRf_3FnL8iztj2LLuB2G4qXUU5aZe_8bv54J3eChnAjgZEpXOjwZ0PX.aDMFrGxPY80WmXuIOd_k7ddLrVufsMXvVGZDkbqPaoyUidc2jukZlTGmbtJsq9PgokEscfHPYWw4KjDZT4js_9x74ME6IB.Pg3f6zuO1S6cb9kuc7WZ6wtRj73lilaXMuXv_mp5N7HB1USXa0Qy.S.PSZOX7kxczmPfD7znequq2Cova59KLDCDgj_kJM8zAGMKDrm7iWBTQuVlpY_lfv5YibTeKfJRtmJYnkJQ.XakDf6k6gOLWmWkJjuA9pVDUZKkMrCXwY8yRInyKIoMPMdPDa4kRIh1ghW2K7VLJfjGu6qXW1kPGFVRTF0wKkN4JKY4J.TLPlSEI9uuudXnam8OY5RZJA--%26lp= - OK
  https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=8j5uUzIGIS8bthoOIIlefINlCyUX0sMagCIuZQ05jmBfB74DwldI_rYOX1OS5kBByKf6VXv1ZfletO8DFuwVrss1EH7zcp7sC3mOkIDCDckHezCh6uetN9gABHeBIVJhY_Gh2YQZYlGcNjg0Ls4p9bZZt6jMNKDm_Deq0awAlb3iWN9MmuRf_3FnL8iztj2LLuB2G4qXUU5aZe_8bv54J3eChnAjgZEpXOjwZ0PX.aDMFrGxPY80WmXuIOd_k7ddLrVufsMXvVGZDkbqPaoyUidc2jukZlTGmbtJsq9PgokEscfHPYWw4KjDZT4js_9x74ME6IB.Pg3f6zuO1S6cb9kuc7WZ6wtRj73lilaXMuXv_mp5N7HB1USXa0Qy.S.PSZOX7kxczmPfD7znequq2Cova59KLDCDgj_kJM8zAGMKDrm7iWBTQuVlpY_lfv5YibTeKfJRtmJYnkJQ.XakDf6k6gOLWmWkJjuA9pVDUZKkMrCXwY8yRInyKIoMPMdPDa4kRIh1ghW2K7VLJfjGu6qXW1kPGFVRTF0wKkN4JKY4J.TLPlSEI9uuudXnam8OY5RZJA--%26lp= - OK
  https://info.yahoo.com/privacy/us/yahoo/relevantads.html - OK
  https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=8j5uUzIGIS8bthoOIIlefINlCyUX0sMagCIuZQ05jmBfB74DwldI_rYOX1OS5kBByKf6VXv1ZfletO8DFuwVrss1EH7zcp7sC3mOkIDCDckHezCh6uetN9gABHeBIVJhY_Gh2YQZYlGcNjg0Ls4p9bZZt6jMNKDm_Deq0awAlb3iWN9MmuRf_3FnL8iztj2LLuB2G4qXUU5aZe_8bv54J3eChnAjgZEpXOjwZ0PX.aDMFrGxPY80WmXuIOd_k7ddLrVufsMXvVGZDkbqPaoyUidc2jukZlTGmbtJsq9PgokEscfHPYWw4KjDZT4js_9x74ME6IB.Pg3f6zuO1S6cb9kuc7WZ6wtRj73lilaXMuXv_mp5N7HB1USXa0Qy.S.PSZOX7kxczmPfD7znequq2Cova59KLDCDgj_kJM8zAGMKDrm7iWBTQuVlpY_lfv5YibTeKfJRtmJYnkJQ.XakDf6k6gOLWmWkJjuA9pVDUZKkMrCXwY8yRInyKIoMPMdPDa4kRIh1ghW2K7VLJfjGu6qXW1kPGFVRTF0wKkN4JKY4J.TLPlSEI9uuudXnam8OY5RZJA--%26lp= - OK
  https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=8j5uUzIGIS8bthoOIIlefINlCyUX0sMagCIuZQ05jmBfB74DwldI_rYOX1OS5kBByKf6VXv1ZfletO8DFuwVrss1EH7zcp7sC3mOkIDCDckHezCh6uetN9gABHeBIVJhY_Gh2YQZYlGcNjg0Ls4p9bZZt6jMNKDm_Deq0awAlb3iWN9MmuRf_3FnL8iztj2LLuB2G4qXUU5aZe_8bv54J3eChnAjgZEpXOjwZ0PX.aDMFrGxPY80WmXuIOd_k7ddLrVufsMXvVGZDkbqPaoyUidc2jukZlTGmbtJsq9PgokEscfHPYWw4KjDZT4js_9x74ME6IB.Pg3f6zuO1S6cb9kuc7WZ6wtRj73lilaXMuXv_mp5N7HB1USXa0Qy.S.PSZOX7kxczmPfD7znequq2Cova59KLDCDgj_kJM8zAGMKDrm7iWBTQuVlpY_lfv5YibTeKfJRtmJYnkJQ.XakDf6k6gOLWmWkJjuA9pVDUZKkMrCXwY8yRInyKIoMPMdPDa4kRIh1ghW2K7VLJfjGu6qXW1kPGFVRTF0wKkN4JKY4J.TLPlSEI9uuudXnam8OY5RZJA--%26lp= - OK
  unknown protocol: javascript
  https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/salman-khan-katrina-kaif-sonakshi-052512176.html - OK
  https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/salman-khan-katrina-kaif-sonakshi-052512176.html - OK
  https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/salman-khan-katrina-kaif-sonakshi-052512176.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/rihanna-narrowly-avoids-wardrobe-malfunction-135255635.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/rihanna-narrowly-avoids-wardrobe-malfunction-135255635.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/rihanna-narrowly-avoids-wardrobe-malfunction-135255635.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/dipika-kakar-set-first-eid-marriage-green-sharara-052512000.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/dipika-kakar-set-first-eid-marriage-green-sharara-052512000.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/dipika-kakar-set-first-eid-marriage-green-sharara-052512000.html - OK
  https://info.yahoo.com/privacy/us/yahoo/relevantads.html - OK
  unknown protocol: javascript
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/neha-kakkar-apologises-her-man-himansh-kohli-rude-073156251.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/neha-kakkar-apologises-her-man-himansh-kohli-rude-073156251.html - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/neha-kakkar-apologises-her-man-himansh-kohli-rude-073156251.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/alia-bhatt-apos-sister-shaheen-031551577.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/alia-bhatt-apos-sister-shaheen-031551577.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/alia-bhatt-apos-sister-shaheen-031551577.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/apos-why-love-island-contestants-183329153.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/apos-why-love-island-contestants-183329153.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/apos-why-love-island-contestants-183329153.html - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=India%20vs%20Afghanistan%202018&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=Bajrang%20Dal%20VHP%20CIA&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=Shujaat%20Bukhari&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=Dhivya%20Suryadevara&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=Luxury%20watches&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=FIFA%20World%20Cup%202018&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=UN%20Kashmir%20report&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=AAP%20dharna&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=Sanju%20poster&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=Race%203&fr=fp-tts&fr2=ps - OK
  https://weather.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/weather/in/maharashtra/pune-2295412/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/weather/in/maharashtra/pune-2295412/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/weather/in/maharashtra/pune-2295412/ - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/weather/in/maharashtra/pune-2295412/ - OK
  null
  null
  null
  https://cricket.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://cricket.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://cricket.yahoo.com/ - OK
  no protocol: 
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/ - OK
  https://in.style.yahoo.com/bengalureans-force-bbmp-re-look-bizarre-new-pet-licensing-bye-laws-notwithoutmydog-movement-095558668.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/photos-eid-ul-fitr-celebrations-slideshow-wp-095013253.html - OK
  https://in.news.yahoo.com/photos-football-frenzy-grips-russia-slideshow-wp-085232287.html - OK
  https://policies.yahoo.com/in/en/yahoo/privacy/index.htm - OK
  http://in.advertising.yahoo.com/ - OK
  careers.yahoo.com
  https://in.help.yahoo.com/kb/helpcentral - OK
  https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/206294-india-homepage - OK
  PASSED: getLinks

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```